# How do you know when to re-evaluate infinite limits to i*infinite limits when making a change of variable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Background: The author is making the point that changes of variables in improper integrals isn't always justified by showing $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x-e^{i\pi/4}}dx (1)\ne\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x'}}{ix'-e^{i\pi/4}}i$dx' (2) where (x=ix'). He does this by considering $\int\frac{e^{iz}}{z-e^{i\pi/4}}dz$. Using residues, $\oint f$dz along the x-axis+quarter circle+y-axis=$2\pi i*e^{ie^{i\pi/4}}=(1)-(2)$ from above which $\ne0$. The minus sign is b/c the integral was $\int_\infty^0=-(2)$

Question: Why Does the change of variable in (2) not become $\int_0^{-i\infty}$ when changing variables? Side question: Does this only apply to improper integrals or do you have to always check for justification when  changing variables between real and imaginary components?

I'm not doubting the point, I just don't understand the change of variable:

```
Integrate[Exp[I x]/(x - Exp[I Pi/4]), x]
=E^(-1)^(3/4) ExpIntegralEi[-I ((-1)^(1/4) - x)]
Integrate[Exp[-x] I/(I x - Exp[I Pi/4]), x]
=E^(-1)^(3/4) ExpIntegralEi[-(-1)^(3/4) - x]
```

---

Original Source text:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your change of variables, $x=ix'$ or, equivalently, $x'=-ix$ (it looks like you have it backwards), so the equation should be $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x-e^{i\pi/4}}dx = \int_0^{-i\infty} \frac{e^{-x'}}{ix'-e^{i\pi/4}}i dx'.$$

There's no reason to expect your integral (2) to equal this.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think the author's point may be merely that you have to be careful to change the limits of integration appropriately when doing a change of variable.

Comment: Yes, I  swapped them accidentally, fixing now. So, THE confusing R might come from the fact that limits of i infinity when Z is limited to the y axis become y or R and he made a slip?

Comment: How about the 2ND  question. Is a change of variable going to be unjustified if a pole is enclosed by a contour around the change and does this only happen with improper integrals?

Comment: Is the integral (2) in the book $\int_0^\infty \dots$ as you wrote it in the question, or is it $\int_0^{-i\infty}\dots?$  Also, what is R, that's not in your question.

Comment: In the book the integral for the change of variables is $\int_0^\infty$ Fixed my mistake. $\int_0^z\frac{e^{iz}}{z-e^{i\pi/e}}$dz is integrated along the y-axis, the i does disappear otherwise a double i would occur in the integral and the limits. Maybe he just forgot the i because of the similar integral? $\lim_{R \to \infty}-\int_0^R\frac{e^{-y}}{iy-e^{i\pi/e}}i$dy is the integral of the contour along the y-axis segment.

Comment: In the equation $2\pi i \,e^{ie^{i\pi/4}}=(1)-(2),$ where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are pieces of the contour integral (with $(2)$ reversed to get the minus sign), $(2)$ would be $\int_0^{-i\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x-e^{i\pi/4}}dx,$ which is equal to $-i\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x}}{-ix-e^{i\pi/4}}dx;$ this isn't the same as the integral you had for $(2).$

Comment: Unless there's some subtlety I'm missing, a change of variable in a definite integral, including changing the limits appropriately so that the implicit path is the same, can't change the value of the integral. If you think in terms of Riemann sums, the two integrals literally represent (limits of) the same finite sums, just written differently.  (It can't make any difference what happens elsewhere in the complex plane.)

Comment: After coming back to this, I figured it out. The author (very good, but sometimes confusing) was trying to explain that the infinite integral on the y axis and x axis couldn't be combined into a single infinite integral to equal the sum of the residues. I can tell English isn't his first language and the wording seems like he's trying to say the integrals aren't the same after the change in variables.